# Apache / NodeJS / Proxy with support for subdirectories

Tags: node.js, apache, mod-proxy

My Apache Config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

My NodeJS:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('Listening on *:3000');
});
```

This currently works when connecting to `mydomain.com`: it will successfully return `index.html`. My problem occurs when I try to connect to `mydomain.com/foo`. Ideally this would simply go to http://localhost:3000/foo but instead it says `"Cannot GET /foo"`.

How would I redirect `mydomain.com/*` to the respective path in my NodeJS project directory without tons of:

```
app.get('/foo', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/foo');
});

app.get('/bar', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/bar');
});

app.get('/foo/bar', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/foo/bar');
});
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the static files serving module with express :

http://expressjs.com/starter/static-files.html

In your case, something like that :

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname, {
  index: 'index.html'
}))
```